# Duplicate __self prop

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs

I have a React Native app built on top of Expo, and recently tried upgrading my Expo sdk from version 48 to 50.

Obviously, it wasn't a smooth transition. I've been clearing errors for a while, but I'm stuck on this one:

> error: node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeViewManagerAdapter.native.js: /Users/maximilianofriedl/Documents/examedi/patient-app/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeViewManagerAdapter.native.js: Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.

It makes a reference to the `transform-react-jsx-source` and `transform-react-jsx-self` plugins on my Babel config, but ... I don't have any of these.

Here is how my **babel.config.js** looks like:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    plugins: [
      "nativewind/babel",
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          loose: true,
        },
      ],
      [
        require.resolve("babel-plugin-module-resolver"),
        {
          root: ["./src/"],
          alias: {
            test: "./test",
          },
        },
      ],
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ],
  };
};
```

I am not sure if this is relevant to the problem or not, but I read somewhere that my **metro.config.js** could be the problem too, so here it is how it looks like:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

// reference: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  assetExts.push("cjs");
  return {
    transformer: {
      assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"],
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  };
})();
```

And the versions of the things I think might matter from my **package.json**:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-expo": "^10.0.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
  "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
},
```

Does anyone has any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The babel-preset package name has changed.
**metro-react-native-babel-preset** was changed to **@react-native/babel-preset**

Uninstall the old one and install the new one, and you should be good to go. It worked in my case.

For more information: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/12/06/0.73-debugging-improvements-stable-symlinks#babel-package-renames

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch that one. I ran into another error now, but at least I'm not stuck on this one anymore

Comment: What's the new error?

Comment: Im getting a: `proc is not a function (it is undefined)`. The source appears to be an `import Animated from "react-native-reanimated"` (on the simulator).

The console says:  ERROR  TypeError: proc is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes